# How do I set the log directory of glog from code

Tags: go, glog

Does anyone know how to set/modify the log dir in the golang source code?
I want to set the log dir in the soure code, instead of `-log_dir=` in the cmdline

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a hack I have seen lying around: set the flags in code.
Also very good for setting log levels from code.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"

    "github.com/golang/glog"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    glog.Info("hi_a")
    flag.Lookup("logtostderr").Value.Set("true")
    glog.Info("hi_b")

    flag.Lookup("log_dir").Value.Set("/path/to/log/dir")

    glog.V(4).Info("v4a")
    flag.Lookup("v").Value.Set("10")
    glog.V(4).Info("v4b")
    //etc.    
}

>>> hi_b
>>> v4b
```

Comment: I was wondering what these getter and setter methods were for.  Note that with this method (lacking a documentation) you can also print the value `glog.Info("Log level: ", flag.Lookup("v").Value)`. Thank you very much. I don't think it's a hack. It is the intended use.

Answer (score 4):

The [glog package](https://github.com/golang/glog) is a dump of the log package used inside Google. Google configures logging using command line flags and that's what the package supports.

You should look to [another log package](http://go-search.org/search?q=logging) or fork the package if you want to set the directory from code.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `logDir` really exist in glog package https://github.com/golang/glog/blob/master/glog_file.go#L41
It just not exported. So you can change it in source of your instance of glog. It's little hacky, but not hard.

Answer (score 0):

First of all *Glog* rely on the package *Flag*. If you will not import it, you will have annoying warning in log message.

If you only need to set parameters one time in initialisation it is very easy.

```
flag.Set("logtostderr", "true")
flag.Parse()
glog.Infof("starting main program")
```